# Adding Phone Number to User Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, twilio

Apologies if this question is too general. I'm relatively new to Rails and development in general. I am creating a Rails app that uses Twilio for SMS verification. Users sign up for the app using their name and phone number. That phone number then gets verified by a pin delivered via SMS. I am having a tough time figuring out whether it would be easier and/or better to use a phone_number model and then create an association between users and phone_numbers using belongs_to: and has_one: or if I can make the phone number a part of the User model.

I am using Rails 4.2.1

Here is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :phone_number
  validates_uniqueness_of :phone_number
end
```

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Saved"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :phone_number, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

This is the Twilio tutorial I've been attempting to follow:

http://twilioinc.wpengine.com/2015/06/sms-phone-verification-in-rails-4-using-ajax-and-twilio.html

Am I overthinking this? Is a user really just a phone_number with a name?

If I do wind up having to create a phone number model/controller, how will I modify my routes? And how would that change my sign up page, which right now includes this:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone_number %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the phone_number model as part of the user and just use the [:user][:phone_number] parameter to create it. It is really up to you and what kind of user experience you are trying to build.

Does the user needs to verify his/her phone number during registration? Does the user has to do it after creating an account?

In the first case, you can make the phone number a separate model which belongs to the user. You put all the methods for the Twilio integration in the phone_number model and use them in the users_controller. You can make the verification step simpler by avoiding AJAX and putting it as a next step of the user registration.

Here's how it might look like:

In your model:

```
    class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :user
       ...
     end
```

In your user controller:

```
 def create
  @user = User.new(permitted_params)
  @phone_number = PhoneNumber.find_or_create_by(user_id: @user.id ,phone_number: params[:user][:phone_number])
  @phone_number.generate_pin
  @phone_number.send_pin
  ...
 end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm going to do. The user does indeed need to verify their phone number in order to complete registration. I can see how to proceed from the initial steps that you've outlined. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the project that you are working on and what you really want to do with your phone number. If it's just a simple use case that a user have a phone number attached to it and you don't have to do any extra work with the phone number, then it's probably a good idea to keep the phone number as an attribute of your user model.

But, in this case, it has somewhat complex usecase. The phone number itself can have different attributes like `number`, `pin` and `verfied` and you have to have a form where you can submit the pin and do stuff based on those. In this case, it's definitely a good idea to create a separate phone_number model and attach that to a user using Rails association.

Again, it can be done either way and really depends on the purpose and requirements of the project.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I chose the other one because of the code snippets, but the similar approach of both of your answers will help me move forward.

Comment: @user2860664 No problem. I also wanted to post some sample codes. But, I was in a rush and had to leave my computer at that time :-) I am happy that you have figured your way and can move forward with your work. +1 for a good question!